# MCV3: View to edit entity has to hold every column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

I got a silly general question...
If I generate a strongly typed view of an entity and chose "edit" as scaffolding, then the view does contain every column for that table. Changing and saving the values via setting it modifierd and call db.SaveChanges() does work in the controller. So far, so good.
**But** if I remove just one of that columns inside the view, then saving doesn't work anymore.

Is there a rule describing this? Is it only possible to make view with **every** column when wanting to save the model later on? I don't want to make 90 of 100 columns "hidden"...

PS: When editing a value in another table which is connected via Foreign Key (like customer.address.STREET) saving also does not work. Does everything of the entity ADDRESS has to be inside the view? I really don't get that.

Besides that: If I create my own ViewModel containing two entities: Do they also have to hold every column of both entities? This would be a whole bunch of traffic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: You should not use the .Modified state. Instead using the UpdateModel method works fine without every field.